# knockout.js 1.3 and jquery templates 1.0pre issue in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, knockout.js, jquery-templates

I am having a major issue with IE8 and the newest versions (beta) of knockout.js and jquery templates.  I keep getting the error below.  If I remove the `<div>` in trialogueRun then it doesn't error.  It happens at the buildTmplFn(markup) function in jquery.tmpl.js.

```
SCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number 
jquery.tmpl.js, line 317 character 9


<script id="trialogueRun" type="text/html">
        <div data-bind="attr: { class: $data.AgentName }"></div>
</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Got it to work with IE8.  I should have known IE would have problems with the word 'class'.

```
<div data-bind="attr: { 'class': $data.AgentName }"></div>
```

Comment: I've had a similar problem with that error in knockout.js v1.2.1 line 928, been searching for ages and this fixed it for me.

Comment: i had the similar problem with knockout.js 2.0.0, this fixed it for me. Good job!